# Google maps API v3 flash empty viewport

Tags: html, flash, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the google maps API v3 with flash and it works fine on one of my websites.

I transfered it to another website and changed the API key, but all I see is the default background color with no error message. Unfortunatly, I cannot access the flash source code.

Is there a way to debug the application or see some error messages without the source code?

Or maybe somebody has an idea of what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Firebug Net](http://getfirebug.com/network) monitor to see if all of the request are going through. That would be the first place that I would start. My guess is that there are HTTP Requests trying to get data from a domain that doesn't have a crossdomain policy allowing access from the new site you moved it to.

Comment: It seems I cannot monitor it since it is a release compilation. But if it is croosdomain problem, how can I solve it?

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Do you have a URL you can share? If it's a crossdomain problem...can you contact the data provider?

Comment: I found a way to create a crossdomain.xml file and it works fine, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all maps V3 doesn't need a  a key. I think you are combining parts of V2 (with key) and V3(which doesn't need key) so obviously there is something wrong in your code.

Comment: That's true for the javascript version, but with the flash version, you need it. I followed the tutorials on google's website.

Comment: This answer ignores the fact that this is about the Flash API. Please delete.

Comment: OTOH, the original question leads to think that you are not using the Flash API (_I'm using the google maps API v3_) so please be more careful as to saying what API you are using exactly ;)